# Is there a way to report data from a URL presented as an XML schema?

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2012

Within Report Builder 3.0, I'd like the option for the user to click on a link that would report based on data contained in an XML URL.

The URL contains a product number in it. The code would contain the URL plus whatever product the user clicks on.

The URL (with a random product  number) looks like this: http://apps.tga.gov.au/prod/ARTGSearch/ARTGWebService.svc/ARTGValueSearch/?licenceid=20000&

Ideally the user would click on a product in report builder and a report would be generated from the data contained within the XML.

Comment: Are the product details in a database somewhere? Are you wanting to use part of this URL as a parameter to be fed into a query to then get results based on it? If the data held is in pure XML form, you may have to transform the data into a more reporting friendly format!

Comment: Hi Harry. They're not in a database I can access. I only have access to the xml output. I suppose I could use VBA to download the data within the various links and upload to a local DB. But was wondering if there is an alternative way of doing this.

Comment: @magametro Not sure how else you can parse the XML on the fly without breaking it down using a tool.. Mine was just an idea.. get the XML and then use a db resource to get what you want out of the XML.